# The type returned by `createAction` isn't maintained through `ofType`

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-observable, redux-toolkit

I'm making an app that lets the user select snacks from a list of available snacks. The snacks are loaded from an external API.

I'm using `redux-observable` to "listen" for actions and then dispatch the appropriate API requests. Here's my existing code, with a comment on the problematic line of code:

```js
// actions.ts

import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import * as Type from './types';

const pfx = '[Snacks]';

export const snackSelect = createAction<Type.Snack['id']>(`${pfx} Select`);

export const snackSelectSuccess = createAction(`${pfx} Select success`);

export const snacksAvailableLoad = createAction(`${pfx} Available load`);

export const snacksAvailableLoadSuccess = createAction<Array<Type.Snack>>(`${pfx} Available load success`);
```

```js
// epics.ts

import {
  combineEpics,
  ofType,
} from 'redux-observable';
import {
  map,
  switchMap,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

import * as API from '../api';

import * as Actions from './actions';

export default combineEpics(
  action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType(Actions.snacksAvailableLoad),
    switchMap(API.snacksGet),
    map(Actions.snacksAvailableLoadSuccess),
  ),

  action$ => action$.pipe(
    ofType(Actions.snackSelect),
    switchMap(({ payload }) => API.snackSelect(payload)), // Error: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Action<any>'
    map(Actions.snackSelectSuccess),
  )

);
```

The `payload` (which should be the target snack id) is not available in my epic's `switchMap`.

I can force it with `switchMap((action: ReturnType<typeof Actions.snackSelect>) => API.snackSelect(action.payload))`, but that `ReturnType<typeof>` seems like code smell and/or rather a lot of boilerplate.

Is there a correct way to preserve typing through `ofType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use `filter` and `.match` then the correct type is inferred:

```js
export default combineEpics(
  action$ => action$.pipe(
    filter(Actions.snacksAvailableLoad.match),
    switchMap(API.snacksGet),
    map(Actions.snacksAvailableLoadSuccess),
  ),

  action$ => action$.pipe(
    filter(Actions.snackSelect.match),
    switchMap(({ payload }) => API.snackSelect(payload)),
    map(Actions.snackSelectSuccess),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I am in the middle of writing you a long-ass answer and then you went and found a simple solution!

Comment: @LindaPaiste to be fair, that's also just what we recommend in the RTK docs ;) https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#alternative-to-using-a-literally-typed-actiontype

Comment: @phry I wish it was more explicitly written somewhere! I completely missed that blurb in the docs.

Comment: Yeah, it's just "too much docs" at some point. Recommendation: use the search function of the docs. I just searched for "observable" and also found https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#with-redux-observable - searching Rxjs will give you the same result :)

Comment: Coming from an Angular/Ngrx background, I kept looking for `ofType` and wouldn't have thought to search for 'filter'. But yes, it's all a balance.

Comment: A docs PR to add a "instead of ofType" so the search picks up on it is very welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too familiar with redux-observable, but it looks like the filtering in the `ofType` function is based of the the type of the `Action['type']` property. See my comments on the type function declaration:

```
export declare function ofType<
  T extends Action,                     // input action type
  R extends T = T,                      // output action type
  K extends R['type'] = R['type']       // type name to filter by
>(...key: K[]): (source: Observable<T>) => Observable<R>;
```

The first issue is that, depending on your TypeScript version, the `type` property of your actions is just `string` and not a literal value like `"[Snacks] Select success"`.  When you are creating a string with a template like `${pfx} Select success` you need to add `as const` in order to avoid widening to `string`.  This is not necessary in v4.3.0+ (which is currently in beta).

Adding `as const` will fix your two actions without a payload. The two which do have a payload will still be `string`.  This is because the `createAction` function has two generic type parameters for the payload `P` and the type `T`.  You cannot specify one parameter and have the second be inferred.  So when you set a generic for the payload you will lose the ability to infer the string literal type and it will fall back to the default value of `string`.

You can always specify both manually:

```
export const snackSelect = createAction<Type.Snack["id"], `${typeof pfx} Select`>(
  `${pfx} Select` as const
);
```

Or create some sort of helper function, since it seems like you have a consistent pattern here.

The second issue is the ability of `ofType` to infer the action type `R` from just the type name `K`.  If your initial action type `T` is a union of your specific action types then that probably happens automatically by extracting the members of union which are assignable to `{type: K}`. But if `T` is a general `any` action then it won't be able to discriminate it.

So you'll need to use some sort of type guard.  Redux-toolkit actions come with a built-in type guard function `match`.

```
declare interface BaseActionCreator<P, T extends string, M = never, E = never> {
    type: T;
    match(action: Action<unknown>): action is PayloadAction<P, T, M, E>;
}
```

...and apparently that's all you need and this resolves the first issue as well.

Comment: Thanks, from 2023. I forgot about the "no inferring" of partially applied generics.